# AWS SDK - WAF & Lambda integration for updating an IP Set List

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

Currently trying to create a slack slash command that triggers an AWS Lambda function. That part is simple enough and is integrated. The lambda function is then supposed to access a specific WAF, grab the IP Set List, and insert an IP address into this list. Essentially, adding a remote IP address to a whitelist, so that remote developers can work on the web development of a website from outside of the firewall.

The problem that I have been having is that I cannot seem to get the AWS - SDK to function properly (obviously my fault haha). I have tried using the SDK to implement my solution in both Java and NodeJS, but have run into two different problems.

**JAVA IMPLEMENTATION**
The main problem with this code is that after executing the code, nothing is added to my ACL whitelist inside of my WAF. 
The code runs in Eclipse. All dependencies should be set up in the environment. Code is being run from the Eclipse environment itself, instead of being triggered from the aws lambda console. Run as so:
[eclipse console screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYmLP.png). The code executes and interacts with the aws sdk. At first, I thought that my code lambda code was incaple of interacting with my AWS account unless the lambda code was deployed and triggered. However, I created some code with the java aws-sdk (in the same function) that creates an S3 bucket.

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Object> {

@Override
public String handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {
    String return_object = "Hello, " + input + "!";
    System.out.println("hello again");
    try {
        createWAF();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // TODO: implement your handler
    return return_object;
}

public void createWAF() throws IOException {
     AWSCredentials credentials = null; // real credentials are passed in non-example code
    /*
     * AWSWAF is an interface. To construct an waf object with access to waf service methods you must 
     * invoke the constructor of AWSWAF--Client
     * pass the credentails as an argument in order to have access to specified AWS account
     */
    AWSWAF waf = new AWSWAFClient(credentials);
    /*
     * When you want to create, update, or delete AWS WAF objects, get a change token and include the change 
     * token in the create, update, or delete request. 
     * Change tokens ensure that your application doesn't submit conflicting requests to AWS WAF.
     * 
     */
    GetChangeTokenResult changeToken = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("change token is converted to PENDING status");
        changeToken = waf.getChangeToken(new GetChangeTokenRequest());
        System.out.println(changeToken.toString());
    } catch (WAFInternalErrorException exception){
        System.out.println("error when initializing ChangeToken param");
        System.out.println(exception.getErrorMessage());
    }


    GetIPSetRequest request = new GetIPSetRequest();
    request.setIPSetId(IPSetId);
    System.out.println("before updating ip set");
    System.out.println(waf.getIPSet(request));

    try{
        /*
         * AWS updateIPSetResult() method states that to create and configure an IPSet, perform the following steps:
         * 1. Submit a CreateIPSet request.
         * 2. Use GetChangeToken to get the change token that you provide in the ChangeToken parameter of an UpdateIPSet 
         * request.
         * 3. Submit an UpdateIPSet request to specify the IP addresses that you want AWS WAF to watch for.
         */

        /*
         * if IP list is already created inside of an ACL - WAF, do you really need to create a new IP set?
         * CreateIPSetRequest createipsetrequest = new CreateIPSetRequest();
         * createipsetrequest.setName("NewIPSet");
         * createipsetrequest.setChangeToken(changeToken.toString());
         * CreateIPSetResult createipset = waf.createIPSet(createipsetrequest);
         */

        /*
         * Must pass a list of parameters to our updateIPSet() call, which includes:
         * 1. a changeToken with empty parameters 
         * 2. the id of the ip set that we want to update
         * 3. a collection of IPSetUpdates, which includes
         *    A) set action -- INSERT IN THIS CASE
         *    B) set type -- IPV4
         *    C) value -- ip address we want to update (arbitrary in this case)
         */
        UpdateIPSetRequest updateParams = new UpdateIPSetRequest();
        updateParams.setChangeToken(changeToken.toString());
        updateParams.setIPSetId(IPSetId); // param exists - redacted in here
        Collection<IPSetUpdate> ipToAdd = new ArrayList<IPSetUpdate>();
        IPSetUpdate howToUpdateIPList =  new IPSetUpdate();
        howToUpdateIPList.setAction(ChangeAction.INSERT);
        IPSetDescriptor ipsetdescriptor = new IPSetDescriptor();
        ipsetdescriptor.setType(IPSetDescriptorType.IPV4);
        ipsetdescriptor.setValue("192.0.2.44/32");
        howToUpdateIPList.setIPSetDescriptor(ipsetdescriptor);
        ipToAdd.add(howToUpdateIPList);
        updateParams.setUpdates(ipToAdd);
        System.out.println("Result: ");
        UpdateIPSetResult result = waf.updateIPSet(updateParams);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (WAFStaleDataException | WAFInternalErrorException e) {
        //exception handling done here
    }
    System.out.println("after updating ip set");
    request.setIPSetId(IPSetId);
    System.out.println(waf.getIPSet(request));
}
```

I will add the NodeJS questions to a separate thread. Thank you for reading this far. I appreciate your time, and any help you can offer.